# filter a single value with RxJS in and return an observable and use the observable via async in a template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a Angular service which correctly return a JSON object via the Angular httpClient. Via an observable I want to read a value of the JSON object in a template in an input field via async.

The async part is allready working only I have problems to retrieve the value from the Json via RXJS.

Java Script object:

```
{
"verbetering": [
{
"entiteit": "S",
"inkoopWaarde": 125000,
"verbeteringBedrag": 3250,
"verbeteringPercentage": 2.6
},
{
"entiteit": "T",
"inkoopWaarde": 125000,
"verbeteringBedrag": 3250,  //In this field is the value I want to show in the template file!!
"verbeteringPercentage": 2.6
}
]
}
```

template code:

```html
<h4>{{ verBeterEuro$ | async }}</h4>
```

Typescript code:

```
verBeterEuro$ = new Observable<number>();

this.verBeterEuro$ = this.improvementService.improvementSubject.pipe(map(y => y.verbetering.filter(y => y.entiteit == 'T'))).pipe((map(w => w  // i am lost...
```

This code works but this is a direct call to the value in the json, that is not usable:

```
this.verBeterEuro$ = this.improvementService.improvementSubject.pipe(map(x => {
      return x.verbetering[1].verbeteringBedrag
}));
```

I want to retrieve the value verbeteringBedrag  when  eniteit is 'T'. In this case is the value which should be showed in the template:  3250

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you almost had it the first time:

```
this.verBeterEuro$ = this.improvementService.improvementSubject.pipe(
  map(
    (y) => {
      const v = y.verbetering.find(vi => vi.entiteit === 'T');
      return v.verbeteringBedrag;
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much @IanT8.....it works like a charm :-).    Yes I was close but I need to practice some more with ES6 and array functions in JavaScript.